# How to save calculated variables in django database and load it after?

Tags: django

I'm making a simple calculation app, but I want to save calculated variables in the database so I can load them after I need them. Thank you

```
def showvideo(request):
    allvideos = Video.objects.all()
    form = VideoForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        sirina = form.cleaned_data.get('sirina')
        visina = form.cleaned_data.get('visina')
        category = form.cleaned_data.get('category')
        roletne = form.cleaned_data.get('roletne')
        okapnice = form.cleaned_data.get('okapnice')
        materijal = form.cleaned_data.get('materijal')
        komore = form.cleaned_data.get('komore')
        krila = form.cleaned_data.get('krila')

        #Example 
        a = 20 + sirina
        b = 30 + visina 
        c = 50 + roletne
        ## I want to save those variables in database and load them after 
        ## in template



        form.save()

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Comment: You shouldn't save values in the database that you can calculate based on other values. But it's not clear from your question what you're saving, is it `Video`? and are `sirina`, `visina` and `roletne` fields on `Video`? And which model should hold the values `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: I want to get values from 'sirina',  'visina' and 'roletne' fields and then calculate them in new variables 'a' , 'b' and ' c' and then save 'a' , 'b' and 'c' to the database and then load them in new template, is that possible? And, no 'a' , 'b' and 'c' doesnt hold any model .  Thank you on your replay

Comment: so `sirina`, etc ... are not saved when you save the form? And I asked which model should hold a, b and c? If you know how to create a model and save it, I don't understand what's your issue, `model = MyModel(a=a, b=b, c=c); model.save()` saves what you want to the database. But as I mentioned before, unless you don't save `sirina`, etc... you should not save calculated values. You're duplicating data that doesn't need to be saved. Calculating `20 + some_model.sirina` every time you fetch the model is faster than saving an extra column in your database.

Comment: Can you help me with code in views.py ? 

    ks = models.IntegerField(editable=False)


####
'ks' will be the calculated field which i want to save in database ?

some_model.ks = 20 + 20 
some_model.save() or some_model.ks  will do the trick ?
I apologize on this stupid questions but im new in django and thank you once again

Comment: you have to try things yourself and ask questions based on what you tried. please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. If you don't try, get errors, debug your errors, you can't learn.

Comment: You have the point, thank you and have a nice day.